# Why am I getting a jQuery is not defined error?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I have to use an external js file in order to load jquery. The code from my js file is below:

```
 document.write('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>');

    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('it works!!');
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

In the firefox firebug console I see this error: "jQuery is not defined" and I think it is because the jQuery library is loaded after the $ function from my js file.

Do you have any idea about how can I fix this? If I run the script from the firebug console everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about jquery not being loaded at the time you call it. You'll have to write a function that will load the jQuery library and only later call your code. Alternatively you can delay your code execution, but this is not 100% full proof.

Update.
[Link to check if jQuery has been loaded](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html) useful for a callback call.

Comment: I think I'll go with writing a js function which loads the code after the jquery also, because I think I've seen such an approach somewhere on SO. TY

Comment: you can write 2 functions: 1 that loads the jquery and 2 that executes  1 with a callback that executes your code. You can also check if jQuery has been loaded. Here are some methods http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html

Answer (score 5):

The generated `<script>` element will appear **after** the current script element, and the code in it will not be executed until after the current `<script>` element's code has finished.

You need to load the library before you start the `<script>` that tries to use it.

Change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('it works!!');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: your right, this solution works, but not when I have to load jQuery from an external js file. Using document.write() with this idea, will make my life a nightmare bc I have to escape all ' and to write the functions in a single line. Can you provide a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `document.write` to pull in jQuery?  Just put the `<script>` tag in the HTML directly.

Comment: bc I NEED that the script to be loaded outside of the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

[Loading scripts dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125897/loading-scripts-dynamically/3125918#3125918) might help you. however, you're trying to load it *while* the page is loading, which would be a bit different from loading it when the page is loaded.

My suggestion is kind of a hack:

```
document.write('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" onload="loaded()" onreadystatechange="loadedIE()"></script>');

function loadedIE() { //for ie
    if(this.readyState == 4){loaded();}
};

function loaded() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('it works!!');
    });
};
```

I think the `readystatechange` listener should work (its an IE hack).