# jQuery not defined - $ not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I googled, checked all the usual responses.. The scripts appear to be in the correct order (they work in this same order in [the demo](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm)) but for some reason when i try to implement it I get the errors.

I have a [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/rcs3CVXN) with my complete page code. But here's the gist of it.

in my header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>     <script src="picker/picker.js"></script>
<script src="picker/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="picker/picker.time.js"></script>
<script src="picker/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="picker/main.js"></script>
```

in my body:

```
<input id="" class="fieldset__input js__datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Choose Date">
<input id="" class="fieldset__input js__timepicker" type="text" placeholder="Choose Time">
```

When I strip everything else out except these parts it works fine. Why is this not working?

**MY ERRORS**

```
[10:23:00.178] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ https://www.nn.com/picker/picker.js:26
[10:23:00.209] ReferenceError: Picker is not defined @ https://www.nnnr.com/picker/picker.date.js:23
[10:23:00.223] ReferenceError: Picker is not defined @ https://www.nnnnnn.com/picker/picker.time.js:23
[10:23:00.245] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ https://www.nnnn.com/picker/main.js:30
```

Comment: Use jQuery instead of $ in your included js

Comment: Try jQuery('. js__datepicker').pickadate(); instead of $('. js__datepicker').pickadate();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538994/jquery-is-not-defined?rq=1

Comment: What is undefined? copy paste the error and post it here. the exact wording of the error is very important, sometimes it's easy to read it the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe you have different versions of jquery in the same html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on an https domain, your includes also need to come from an https domain.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

And, if you're site can be both http and https, you can make it protocol relative so that it automatically switches to whatever is needed.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

note however that using the protocol relative one only works if you're running the code from a webserver (which, to be honest, should always be the case.)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could leave off the protocol.. it was the https! thankks

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your function like this:

```
(function($){
$(whatever).click(function(){ alert('this should be working');})
})(jQuery)
```

or you can try to add

```
var $ = jQuery
```

on top of your js file

Comment: Note, `var $ = jQuery ` can be destructive to other parts of your code.